# Merge synonyms for tags on Meta

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are a few duplicate tags on our meta site that need to be synonymised (is that even a word?):

- [new-user](/questions/tagged/new-user) > [new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users)
- [user-accounts](/questions/tagged/user-accounts) > [users](/questions/tagged/users)
- [flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging) > [flags](/questions/tagged/flags)
- [answering](/questions/tagged/answering) > [answers](/questions/tagged/answers)

Note that while some of these may be pointing to another tag with less question, they have all been chosen to be synomised with the tag with the better name.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I've actioned most of these years ago:

- [new-user](/questions/tagged/new-user) > [new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users)
- [flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging) > [flags](/questions/tagged/flags)
- [answering](/questions/tagged/answering) > [answers](/questions/tagged/answers)

The only one I haven't is [user-accounts](/questions/tagged/user-accounts) -> [users](/questions/tagged/users). Not every question about user accounts is about users (and vice-versa) - they're different concepts. I think those ones should remain separate.